# Get email using Hunter IO API with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello fellow developers,

I am trying to get the email count for any website using Hunter IO free API with Google Apps Script.

Hunter IO API reference : https://hunter.io/api/v2/docs#email-count

Here is my code.

```
function checkDomain() {
  var domain = 'stripe.com'; 
  var url = 'https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-count?domain='+domain; 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(domain);
  var result = response.getContentText();   
  Logger.log(JSON.parse(result));   //  <-- Line 56 
}
```

I get this Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token: < (line 56, file "Code")

Can anyone please help me understand this error and tell me how to retrieve a JSON response from this Hunter IO.

Comment: You have an error in your code....its really obvious. Check line-by-line and you'll see it.

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `url` and not `domain` variables.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

I would also recommend the use of string constructors. Its increase readability and understanding of the code.

```
var domain = 'stripe.com';
var template = 'https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-count?domain=%s';
var url = Utilities.formatString(template, domain);
```

Comment: Thank you very much and really sorry for asking this question without enough investigation. Thanks again for helping me out. It had passed domain instead of url. It's working now.